# What does it mean to say something is only a process not an end in itself?

Tags: meaning

English is not my native language and I came across the sentence "devolution is a process not an end in itself" and I want to know the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: 'Devolution' is a rather nebulous concept: when can it be said to be over? When officials are replaced/retasked? A charter signed? Using 'education is a process not an end in itself', the education is necessary and hopefully good, but the desired end is a well-rounded and trained person.

Answer (score 1):

"*Not an end in itself*" is used to explain that something is **just a means** in obtaining a certain result, this result being what is also called the *end*. For instance the end of education is not to accumulate knowledge for yourself and do nothing with that knowledge  merely relishing in the satisfaction that this work of assimilation provides--if it provides any--but it is to go through such a task of accumulation  with the prospect of putting that knowledge to use once the process of getting it has been completed.

It is not different for "devolution"; the remark--as it can be but a remark in a special context--is truer than for most activities since in "devolution" what is involved is a transfer of something (rather abstract): power, responsability, property. The sole end can only be the effected transfer, that is the taking up of responsabilities by a new entity, new politician, new governing body, etc.

- *(SOED) Descent by natural, legal, or due succession; the action of passing something on to a successor; the deputing or delegation of work or authority to; especially the transfer of some powers by the British or UK House of Parliament to bodies appointed by and responsible to it, or by central government to a local or regional administration, esp. in  Scotland and Wales. (Mid 18th century)*

Answer (score 1):

Devolution suggests something that causes passing to a relatively worse state or position, but it does not prescribe how much worse the next-in-time position is.  The term only suggests the worsening process akin to rolling down a hill, for example.  The degree or measure of negative difference over the devolution period describes the end.

This term is confusing because it also has a very technical legal meaning.  Title to property that passes automatically by rule of law, say upon the death of an individual to that person’s heirs, is said to devolve.

Answer (score 0):

The political web site "[They Work for you](https://www.theyworkforyou.com/sp/?id=2008-11-27.12891.0)" has a verbatim report from the Scottish Parliament. Christine Grahame (Scottish National Party) gives a speech. In this context, "Devolution" = the political process that will lead to Scotland becoming an independent country. The speech ends:

> Since 1999, the [Scottish] Parliament has grown in maturity and skill—attributes that have even, on occasion, been displayed in debates. For some members, devolution is a process, not an end in itself.

She is saying that devolution is a process (that will lead to independence) - it is not the goal - that is independence itself..